# Intellij IdeaVim: use right mouse button drag to move cursor up and down

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I like to zip through lengthy source files quickly. I find ctrl-e/y too jumpy. Smooth scrolling isn't work well enough. Scroll wheel is too slow.
Way back when I made my own vi clone and what I did there is I made the right mouse button dragging scroll the window. This allowed me to zip through source much faster.
Can this be achieved in ideavim as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is no user-exposed configuration for that in IdeaVim. You have to modify its source code. I doubt it would make a good pull request though, since you're the first person ever to request this feature. I guess the simplest workaround is to tweak the scrolling speed of your mouse in the OS settings.